# sub_filter doesn't work when used with MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki, nginx

I'm working on a site, https://factinfiction.meulie.net/ . This site runs the latest stable version of MediaWiki (1.26.2).

In the server-config I have the following location-block:

```
location / {
sub_filter '</head>' '<meta name="author" content="Evert Meulie"></head>';
sub_filter_once on;
sub_filter_last_modified on;
sub_filter_types *;

try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
```

This works fine with a testfile: https://factinfiction.meulie.net/test.html gets the meta-tag added.
However, it does not work on any of the MediaWiki pages, like https://factinfiction.meulie.net/Main_Page

How do I fix this? I thought [sub_filter](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html#sub_filter) was the last process code passes through before it gets sent out, and that it would work no matter the application...

Comment: I see `$ curl -Is https://factinfiction.meulie.net/Main_Page | grep Server
Server: cloudflare-nginx`, are you sure the CloudFlare cache was purged? I see there are multiple extensions to alter the meta tags in https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Search_engine_optimization_extensions but not for all pages at once, apparently. https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T31968#336350 would be another solution.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this one?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't recall, @adrelanos...